# How to start the cron daemon

Tags: rhel, cron, services

I am using RHEL 5.4

I killed the cron daemon accidentally. I wanted to stop a cron task, didn't know how to do it, ended up killing the cron daemon itself. How do I start it again?

Comment: It could depend on the linux distro you use. So update your answer with this information, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how your exact distribution is set up, `/etc/init.d/cron start` or variations thereupon might do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are on RHEL you may like to use the more practical:

```
service crond start
```

If you just type

```
service crond
```

and hit `Enter`, you will see all the implemented available options for the previous command:

```
Usage: /etc/init.d/crond {start|stop|status|reload|restart|condrestart}
```